# How to Validate html5 forms in html5 unsupported browsers

Tags: jquery, html, validation, required

I am developing an erp solution using asp.net and c#, I'm in the front-end development team.I have added form validation using html 5 validation method instead of asp validator control. but the problem is it is not supporting for html 5 unsupported browsers, Is there any way to solve this ?

example field ::

```
 <input type="text" required />
```

Comment: Hey folks, this question is very specific and should not be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Webshim has a really nice HTML 5 form validation polyfill.

http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/

Your properties for `required` and `pattern` work right out of the box.